# Can however be used to mean something else other than contrast?

Tags: however-placement

Here are the sentences:

1. With sea otters to keep the population of sea urchins in check, kelp forests can flourish. In fact, even two years or less of sea otter presence can
   reduce the sea urchin threat.

Then should the following sentence be 2 or 3?

2. **However**, without sea otters present, kelp forests run the danger of becoming barren stretches of coastal wasteland known as urchin barrens.

OR

3. **In other words**, without sea otters present, kelp forests run the danger of becoming barren stretches of coastal wasteland known as urchin barrens.

I understand that "however" is used to contrast. "In other words" means "in short" or "another way of saying the same thing". Can someone demonstrate if "however" or "in other words" makes more sense with the sentences above? I think the "however" is used incorrectly here. If both are correct, how can that be? (However is for contrast and in other words is for saying the same thing)

Comment: It's a bad example, because it confuses / conflates the normally quite distinct meanings of ***however*** and ***in other words***. Bottom line: ***however*** normally introduces *new information* which somehow contrasts/conflicts with earlier text.  Your context is *If A then B [linking term] If NOT A then NOT B*. It's really a matter of opinion how to link those two assertions. You could just as well defend ***but, however, although*** as ***thus, therefore, that is to say, in other words***.

Comment: I agree that this is a bad question. The answer says it's supposed to be "however" but I can also see why "in other words" or "hence" and the other words you chose, such as "that is to say" would also work.

Comment: We can survive as long as we have oxygen. However/In other words, if we run out of oxygen, we die.

Comment: 'In other words' is incorrect here as 'without sea otters present, kelp forests run the danger of becoming barren stretches of coastal wasteland known as urchin barrens.' has not been stated previously in any form.

Comment: Wouldn't "moreover" work here?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  is correct here.

Comment: Them's strong words, @EdwinAshworth.  yourdictionary.com: "He has another appointment on Thursday. In other words, I don't think he'll be attending your gathering." The fact that he may not be attending the gathering is NOT mentioned in any form in the first sentence. This expression is used very commonly to introduce leaps of logic. thefreedictionary.com: " Henry: Sure I want to do it, but how much do I get paid? Andrew: In other words, you're just doing it for the money. Bill: Well, I suppose I really should prepare my entourage for departure. Bob: In other words, you're leaving?"

Comment: @Chuck Hubbard I quite agree. The looser sense is encountered commonly in conversation. However, OP's example is in a far more formal register, and scientists tend to be precisionist.

Comment: @HeyDoeFarm ~ As you pointed out correctly, *however* is used incorrectly here. *In other words* works perfectly fine, because it simply introduces a restating of the original statement, for the purpose of clarification. As you know, *however* does introduce a contrasting statement, which is inappropriate here.

Comment: Incidentally, "however" can be used to mean something other than contrast, but not in this example. It could be e.g. "I will prepare it however you want."

Comment: @Chuckk Hubbard ~ Ah, so *whatever* is perfectly good grammar as well -- I knew it!!

Comment: @ChuckkHubbard I wanted to follow up with a question from your previous example. Would "Hence, if we run out of oxygen, we die" also work since FumbleFingers mentioned that "therefore" would work as well?

Comment: @Bread and Chuckk Hubbard. Yes I agree and I don't see how the second sentence is actually in contrast with the first sentence, making "however" to be incorrect.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say. "However" and "whatever" are different and used differently. I agree that it's not exactly a contrast to say, e.g., "I like chocolate. My sister likes vanilla." So "however" would seem out of place there. So would "in other words".

Answer (score -2):

HeyDoeFarm, to me 'lest' (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lest) would be a better word in this subject's context as opposed to "Hence" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hence).